# CakePHP - Issue with Login function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Here is the code

**`UsersController.php`**

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}

?>
```

**`User.php` (model file)**

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel
{

    public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**`login.ctp` (view file)**

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));
?>
```

**`AppController.php`**

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'books',
                'action' => 'view'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'home'
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Table name : users

I am a new to CakePHP, I just written the code for simple login action,
When I tried to login with correct credentials, It always showing **incorrect username and password**

`$this->Auth->login()` is always returns the false value even I give correct username and password. Please give me a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Are you implementing the password hasher?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

> In CakePHP database, table name should be a plural. Model name should be a singular nount with CamelCase. Controller should be a plural with CamelCase add suffix *Controller* must be added. View folder name always is the same as Controller plural name (without suffix) and `.ctp` file name should be a verb.

**AppController.php**

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'RequestHandler','Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'Autoredirect'=>false,
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'view'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
            'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        )
    );
}    
?>
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Js','Session');
        public $components = array(
            'RequestHandler',
            'Session'
    );

public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                 $this->Session->setFlash('You are successfully login','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-success'));  
                 return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
          return  $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username and password,please try again','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'));    
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**login.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>  
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username');?>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password');?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
     <?php echo $this->Form->button('Login',array('type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block')); ?>   
</div>  
  <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**AppModel.php**

```
 App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
    class AppModel extends Model {
        public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha1'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
        public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
            if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
                $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha1'));
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
                );
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**User.php (User Model)**

```
<?php
        class User extends AppModel
        {
         public $validate = array(
            'username' => array(
                'alphaNumeric' => array(
                    'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                    'required' => true,
                    'message' => 'Letters and numbers only'
                ),

            ),
            'password' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
                'message' => 'Minimum 8 characters long'
            ),
        );
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But its not working again same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally i have limited the password field in the database so that password stored partially in the DB that is the reason for this issue.